# Mutt email client not working

Tags: email, mutt

Having issues running the mutt command on Ubuntu Linux

Which mutt: 
/usr/bin

```
/usr/bin/mutt -s “test” -a  /var/sftp/file.txt email@domain.com
```

Does not work. Also tried this:

```
cat file.txt | mutt -s “test” email@domain.com
```

not sure what I am doing wrong any advice would be great.

Comment: Works well here but you may be missing 2 things: 1. A working ~/.muttrc file 2. A decent Mail Delivery Agent such as msmtp. Background here: http://www.andrews-corner.org/mutt.html

Comment: Got this to work with plain text in config file, however trying to encrypt password and getting error. I will ask a new question